# How can I enhance this query to use only one view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL and DB, I need to make the following query, I need to make a query that finds the dates that there were more car crashes and list the names of the people who were involved in these car crashes

```
person
| name   | id_person  |
|--------|------------|
| Oliver | 000000001  |
| Harry  | 000000002  |
| Jacob  | 000000003  |
| Maria  | 000000004  |
| Jack   | 000000005  |
```

---

```
participated
| id_person  | num_crash   | cost_damage   |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
|  00000001  |  11111101   |      200      |
|  00000002  |  11111102   |      120      |
|  00000003  |  11111102   |      120      |
|  00000004  |  11111103   |      400      |
|  00000005  |  11111104   |      300      |
|  00000002  |  11111105   |      280      |
|  00000005  |  11111106   |      260      |
```

---

```
crash
| num_crash   | date_crash   | crash_scene |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|
|  11111101   |  2020/04/28  |  bairro 4   |
|  11111102   |  2020/05/01  |  bairro 1   |
|  11111103   |  2020/05/01  |  bairro 2   |
|  11111104   |  2020/05/04  |  bairro 3   |
|  11111105   |  2020/05/04  |  bairro 1   |
|  11111106   |  2020/05/04  |  bairro 3   |
```

---

```
output example 
| data_crash   | num_crash   | name  |
|--------------|-------------|-------|
|  2020/05/04  |  11111104   | Jack  |
|  2020/05/04  |  11111105   | Harry |
|  2020/05/04  |  11111106   | Jack  |
|  2020/05/01  |  11111102   | Harry |
|  2020/05/01  |  11111102   | Jacob |
|  2020/05/01  |  11111103   | Maria |
```

This is my sql query

```
CREATE VIEW vwfrequencedatecrash AS 
SELECT date_crash, num_crash, crash_scene, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION 
BY date_crash ORDER BY date_crash) AS frequence 
FROM crash 
ORDER BY frequence DESC;

CREATE VIEW vwmorefrequencedate AS 
SELECT date_crash, num_crash, crash_scene, frequence 
FROM vwfrequencedatecrash 
WHERE frequence > 1;

SELECT vw.date_crash, pa.num_crash, p.name 
FROM vwmorefrequencedate vw 
JOIN crash c ON c.date_crash = vw.date_crash 
JOIN participated pa ON c.num_crash = pa.num_crash
JOIN person p ON pa.id_person = p.id_person
ORDER BY vw.frequence DESC, c.date_crash;
```

how can I improve this query?

Comment: You don't need any additional views for this.  MySQL now allows subqueries in the `FROM` clause of views.

Comment: Views in MySQL serve no useful purpose - at least not one I've managed to discern